# Minmum number of calls needed for n gossipers to accomplish exact $k$-gossiping

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $E(n,k)$ be the minimum number of calls needed for $n$ gossipers to accomplish exact $k$-gossiping.

I read that if $n=2k-1$ and $k\ge 5$ then $E(n,k)=4k-10$.

Is anyone can explain to me why is $4k-10$?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you read that? The only source I could easily find was a paper from 1997 citing an earlier paper's claim that $E(2k-1,k) \le 4k-9$ for $k \ge 4$.

Comment: Base on the paper the published by chang and tsay in 1996

Comment: I found a [1996 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9400257J) by Chang and Tsay on partial gossiping, which does not mention the exact problem at all, and a [1997 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96003172) that I already mentioned, which only mentions $E(2k-1,k) \le 4k-9$, a result due to [Richards and Liestman](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230180205/full). What else am I mising?

Comment: see the proof in the next comment

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the proof that $E(n,k)<=4k−10$ for $k>=5$ and $n=2k-1$
Proof:

Let divide the 2k-1 gossiper to two foreignness groups like this:

P which will contain $k$ gossiper: $P={p_1,p_2,...p_k}$

Q which will contain the rest $k-1$ gossiper: $q={q_1,...,q_(k-1)}$

Here the gossip algorithm:

1) each gossiper from group P will talk with the gossiper that after him
i.e: in time $i$ when $1<=i<=k-1$: $p_i$ will speak with $p_(i+1)$
after this phase: $p_1$ know 2 details, $p_2$ know 3 details,...$p_(k-1)$ know $k$ details, $p_k$ know $k$ details

(number of calls to this phase is: $K-1$ calls)

2)$p_1$ which has 2 details (his detail and $p_2$ detail) will have full gossip with the group q \ {$q_(k-1)$} (group q without $q_(k-1)$) after this phase each gossiper will know $k$ pieces of information

(number of calls to this phase is: as full gossip in group of k-1 gossiper: $2(k-1)-1 = 2k-6)$

3)$q_(k-1)$ (that know only his piece of information) will talk with $p_(k-2)$ which know exactly $k-1$ piece of information and know each one of them knowing exactly $k$ piece of information

(number of calls to this phase is: $1$)

4)now $p_(k-2)$ will talk each one from the gossiper in the group P \ { $p_1$ , $p_(k-1)$ , $p_k$}
after this phase each one from the gossiper will know $K$ piece of information! ( $p_(k-2)$ knew $k-1$ details from the first phase and it $k$ details from the previous phase)

(number of calls to this phase is: $k-4$)

So let's sum the number of calls:
$k-1 + 2k-6 + 1 + k-4 = 4k - 10$

(I hope it was understandable)